# Get the identity of the image loaded at the centre of the screen currently?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a uiscrollview with contentsize 1280*1280 and 25 images of equal size loaded in it. When i scroll and meet an end, I want to know the identity of the image which is currently present at the screen centre. Given below is the code that i used to load the images into the scrollView. How can i figure it out?

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if(j == 5)
    {
        tx = tx+1;
        x=x+256;
        ty = ty+5;
        y = y-1280;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://stage.discoveritalia.it/tiles/%d/%d/%d.png",zoom,tx,ty]]]]];
        frame = [imageView frame];
        frame.origin.x = x;
        frame.origin.y = y;
        [imageView setFrame:frame];
        [myScrollView addSubview:imageView];

        ty = ty-1;
        y = y+256;

        [imageArray insertObject:imageView atIndex:i*5+j];
        [imageView release];
     }
}
```

If I could get the URL back, it would solve my problem right away. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Calculate the `CGPoint` at the center of the screen (depending on orientation)
2. Divide the `x` and `y` values by `1280 / 5` and add `((1280 / 5) / 2)` to determine the tile `i-j` indices that the center would overlap, with no `UIScrollView` offset
3. Now add the current scroll view offset to determine which tile the center actually overlaps

Comment: Problem is I know which tile is there but want to get its name,ie for eg,http://stage.discoveritalia.it/tiles/10/6028/5078.png. I want to take that into a string, then parse it and get the last two integer values. And depending on it I should load the next 25 images surrounding them with the one i got at the centre of the contentSize. All this for doing infinte UIScrollView.

Comment: Hey, i figured it out. Just store all the urls or more specifically the 2 values in the url that I want in an array. As per ur formula I will get an x and y. x*5+y will give me the index of that array, which will give me the value. Thanks a lot.